# How to fix problem with zfs mount after upgrade to 12.0-RELEASE?

Tags: freebsd

So I had to upgrade my system from 11.1 to 12.0 and now the system does not load. Stop on error Trying mount root zfs - Error 2 unknown filesystem.

And I do not have an old kernel which was good and worked well.
So How to fix mount problem?

Had tried to boot with the old kernel, but after one of the tries to freebsd-update upgrade there left only new kernel.

Expected no problems after the upgrade.
Actual - cannot load the system with Error 2 - unknown filesystem

P.S.
Found that /boot/kernel folder does not contain opensolaris.ko module.
How to copy this module to /boot partition on the system from LiveCD (this file exist on LiveCD)

Comment: Check that in `/boot/loader.conf` you have `zfs_load="YES"` and in `/etc/rc.conf` `zfs_enable="YES"`

Comment: i can't check because the filesystem can not mount without kernel module opensolaris.ko

Comment: on the boot sequence (https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/boot-introduction.html) try  `load boot/kernel.old/opensolaris.ko` or the path to `opensolaris.ko`

Comment: I have not opensolaris.ko on the system after upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a FreeBSD USB stick ready... you can import the pool into a live environment and then mount individual datasets manually.

Considering "*zroot*" is your pool name

```
# mount -urw /
# zpool import -fR /mnt zroot
# zfs mount zroot/ROOT/default
# zfs mount -a // in case  you want datasets  to mount
# cd /mnt
```

Now do whatever you want...
You can also rollback to the last working snapshot (if there is any)
In case, your system is encrypted, you need to decrypt it first.

Comment: i do this like you wrote. After i had mount zroot pool i don't see /boot folder so i ca not to copy "opensolaris.ko" module to kernel folder to fix mount error on the boot.

Comment: You could have rollback to the last snapshot too.

Comment: What snapshot? How to rollback it?